# Login user to other sites?

Tags: php, curl, autologin

Is there any way to login users to other sites using PHP with cURL or something else?
I want to provide logins for my users to other sites, but i don't want to show them the password, so they cannot change it on the other sites.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more? You want them to log in with their credentials, through your interface? Sounds a bit shady. If it's giving them a login with your credentials, hence why you need to hide your password, please say so as well. In that case the method may vary depending what sites you're logging into.

Comment: No. for example, i have a rapidshare account. And i want the users to log in with this account, but i don't want to provide the password, because thay can change it. So i want to login them with my account, but they shouldn't see the login details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not unless you proxy the entire session through your server.

Comment: I should need a cross site solution, so i guess the answer is no. Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is it depends on the site.

Websites have a variety of ways to authenticate a user. If the website uses a session identifier in the URL, you *could* login for them, then pass a `header('Location: http://someothersite.com?PHPSESSID=_____');` to the user and assume it just picks up with that session.

If they use cookies or IP-based system, it won't work because

a) you can't pass another domain's cookie on to the end-user (this would be a X-site attack), and
b) the server's IP is different than the users.

You might be able to fake that you're a proxy and use X-FORWARDED-FOR in your request, but even still that's a stretch.

Answer (score 0):

SAML is often used for signle sign on (SSO) - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Assertion_Markup_Language